# Would a question about arranger intent be too broad or not suited for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I would like to ask if anything is known about the reasons why Liszt decided to introduce some pretty significant changes/additions to the piano transcription of **Danse macabre** by Camille Saint-Saens compared to the original orchestral piece. I'm not really looking for opinions of why he *might* have done it, but more something along the lines of actual quotes or general facts about his transcription style and his intentions.

However, I'm still not completely sure whether this question would fit the Q&A format of this site or if it might be considered not specific enough/too broad, so I thought I'd first make sure here on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a decent historical question to me.  Just be clear about your intentions, as you were here, and it should be fine!